# Python calculate arrangements of sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinatorics

I have just started thinking about probabilities. A Problem that come up was how to calculate all the potential arrangements for a given sequence. By arrangement I mean unique permutation.

I initially used this method:

```
from itertools import permutations

sequence = '11223344'
len(set(permutations(sequence)))
# 2520
```

But for long sequences this can take a long time! (or run out of memory)

I came up with this function `arrangements`

```
from math import factorial
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul

def arrangements(sequence):
    return factorial(len(sequence))/reduce(mul,
           [factorial(sequence.count(i)) for i in set(sequence)])

# arrangements(sequence)
# 2520.0
```

My thinking is this:

For a given length sequence with all unique items there are `factorial(len(sequence))` permutations.

For every repeated item in the sequence there will be `factorial(#repeats)` that will result in the same permutation.

My function calculates all permutations / all repeated permutations.

I'm sure I have reinvented an already existing standard python function somewhere. I'd like to know if my thinking is sound and the implementation makes sense.

Wouldn't `itertools.arrangements` be cool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Notes

- I'd expect `arrangements` to return the unique permutations of `sequence`, not just how many there are.
- If it returns a number, it should be an integer.
- You could use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead of counting the integers again and again.
- You're right, it would be nice to have `itertools.unique_permutations`. In the meantime, I often come back to this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6285203/6419007).

## Possible refactoring

```
from math import factorial
from functools import reduce
from collections import Counter
from operator import mul


def count_unique_permutations(sequence):
    count_permutations = factorial(len(sequence))
    repetitions = (factorial(v) for v in Counter(sequence).values())
    return count_permutations // reduce(mul, repetitions)
```

Comment: Hadn't considered using `Counter`, it looks better :)

Answer (score 3):

The keyword to search for is "multinomial coefficient". That returns this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46374185/does-python-have-a-function-which-computes-multinomial-coefficients

Comment: Good to know. The linked code isn't very readable IMHO but it has the merit of not needing 4 imports for 4 lines of code.

Comment: Thanks for the Terminology. @EricDuminil at least all imports are from the standard library.